# The term 'Add-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I use Add Library Package Reference and add reference on HTML Agility Pack and NewtonSoft.JSON.

Then I try add reference on one of these assemblies to my test project from console with this commands.

```
PM> Add-Package HTML Agility Pack
```

I get this error:

> The term 'Add-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>       At line:1 char:12
>       + Add-Package <<<<  HTML Agility Pack
>           + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

What is bad, also Intellisense is not working.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 x86 I have installed NuGet 1.0 RTM.

And last problem is possible add reference on Caliburn Micro or Managed Extensibility Framework?

I hope that package are installed:

```
PM> get-package
```

*Id                                                    Version                                               Description

HTML Agility Pack                                     1.4                                                   An agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM...
Newtonsoft.Json                                       4.0.1                                                 Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON frame...*

**EDITED:**

I try `PM> install-package HTML Agility Pack`

> Install-Package : Cannot bind parameter 'Version'. Cannot convert value "Pack" to type "System.Version". Error: "Version string portion was too short or too long."

Answer (score 3):

Put "HTML Agility Pack" in quotes

```
Install-Package "HTML Agility Pack"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this: `Find-Package -remote -filter html` which gave me the following:

> Id               Version  Description
>   --               -------  -----------
>   HtmlAgilityPack  1.4.0    This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write...

So making use of the command `Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack` downloads the package you're after.

A handy tip btw: if you type in `install-package html` and then followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> then the choices, at the moment of writing this still only one, choices appear.